# Is there a way to get innerText of only the top element (and ignore the child element's innerText)?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

Is there a way to get innerText of only the top element (and ignore the child element's innerText) ?

Example:

```
<div> 
   top node text 
   <div> child node text </div>
</div>
```

How to get the "top node text" while ignoring "child node text" ? innerText property of top div seem to return concatenation of both inner , top text.

Comment: Remove the non text direct child nodes first?

Comment: @Oded: No need. Just iterate over the children and concatenate. Easy peasy.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Just iterate over the child nodes and concatenate text nodes:

```
var el = document.getElementById("your_element_id"),
    child = el.firstChild,
    texts = [];

while (child) {
    if (child.nodeType == 3) {
        texts.push(child.data);
    }
    child = child.nextSibling;
}

var text = texts.join("");
```

Comment: +1 Clearly better than cloning what may be a very large bit of DOM tree, just to discard most of it. Only improvement would be `text = []` at the start, and then `text.push(child.data)` per iteration, and finally `text = text.join('')` at the end to turn the array of pieces into a string, which tends to be faster than repeated concatenations to an ever-growing string.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: I considered that, but I think the last benchmarks I saw suggested it was not clear cut that it actually improves performance so I went for the simpler version. I'll check now.

Comment: Nice one. PS. `data` is the defined in the [`CharacterData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/CharacterData) interface, which is implemented by `Text` (text nodes).

Comment: @DanielEarwicker: Seems as though array join may well be slower in modern browsers but is way quicker in IE 7, which trumps everything since your slowest target browser is where you actually need performance gains. Amending...

Comment: Instead 3 you can use Node.TEXT_NODE [Source](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_nodetype.asp) (See named constants)

Comment: @WilliamArdila: True. It was true in 2012 except for IE <= 8, which hadn't gone away by that point.

Answer (score 13):

This will work in your example: 
`document.getElementById("item").firstChild.nodeValue;`

> Note: Keep in mind that this will work if you know you are dealing with that specific HTML. If your HTML can change, for example to:

```html
<div> 
    <div class="item"> child node text </div>
    top node text 
</div>
```

> then you should use the more generic solution by [@Tim Down](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9340862/567897)

---

Here is working code snippet:

```js
window.onload = function() {
   var text = document.getElementById("item").firstChild.nodeValue;
   document.getElementById("result").innerText = text.trim();
};
```

```css
#result {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div id="item">
  top node text 
   <div> child node text </div>
</div>



<strong>Result:</strong> <div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: This doesn't work if the sequence of the HTML is changed. I.e, if the `div` is the first child. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921283/6908282) by @ehsaneha works in this case

Answer (score 4):

1. Clone the element.
2. Loop through all child nodes (backwards, to avoid conflicts):
   If the element has a `tagName` attribute, then it's an element: Remove the node.
3. Use `innerText` to get the textual contents (with fallback to `textContent`, when `innerText` is not supported).

Code:

```
var elem = document.getElementById('theelement');
elem = elem.cloneNode(true);
for (var i=elem.childNodes.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    if (elem.childNodes[i].tagName) elem.removeChild(elem.childNodes[i]);
}
var innerText = elem['innerText' in elem ? 'innerText' : 'textContent'];
```

Comment: Wow, works like charm in all browsers. Frankly, I didn't think it was possible before posting the question :) ... thank you...

Comment: No need to clone or mutate the DOM at all. Just read the text node children. See my answer.

Comment: @ivymike Tims's method is better. I suggest to accept his answer instead of mine. It also works in all browsers (tested in IE6+, Chrome 1+, Safari 5, Firefox 3+).

Answer (score 4):

```js
function getDirectInnerText(element) {
  var childNodes = element.childNodes;
  result = '';

  for (var i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++) {
    if(childNodes[i].nodeType == 3) {
      result += childNodes[i].data;
    }
  }

  return result;
}

element = document.querySelector("div#element");
console.log(getDirectInnerText(element))
```

```html
<div id="element"> 
   top node text 
   <div> child node text </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid code-only answers.
Also, you could change the `3` to `Node.TEXT_NODE` to use fewer literals and increase readability

Answer (score 1):

As every other answer already explained, you need to check the type of the childnode.

Here is a neat one-liner based on [@ehsaneha's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56921283/3735561):

```
Array.from(element.childNodes).reduce((x, y) => x + (y.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ? y.data : ''), '').trim()
```

Or as a prototyped method:

```
Element.prototype.directInnerText = function () {
    return Array.from(this.childNodes).reduce((x, y) => x + (y.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE ? y.data : ''), '').trim();
}
```

usage:

```
console.log(document.body.querySelector('.element').directInnerText());
```

Compatibility reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nodeType?retiredLocale=de

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to ignore the child element's inner text, use the following function:

```
function getInnerText(el) {
    var x = [];
    var child = el.firstChild;
    while (child) {
        if (child.nodeType == 3) {
            x.push(child.nodeValue);
        }
        else if (child.nodeType == 1) {
            var ii = getInnerText(child);
            if (ii.length > 0) x.push(ii);
        }
        child = child.nextSibling;
    }
    return x.join(" ");
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something, or is this the opposite of what they're asking for?

Answer (score 0):

```
const nodeValues=[];
document.querySelectorAll("locator").forEach(
    function (currentValue) {
        nodeValues.push(currentValue.firstChild.nodeValue);
    }
)
return nodeValues;
```