# Converting html text into plain text

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id = "id1">
    "some text 1"<br>
    "more text 2" <br>
    "name" <br>
    <li> "list 1"</li>
    "THEend"
    <div class="class1" style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px;">
      &nbsp;&nbsp;
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following JavaScript:

```
var contents  = document.getElementsById("id1").innerHTML
```

Currently, the result of `contents` includes the text from both `id1` and `class1` -- but I want to eliminate the contents of `class1` entirely.

How should I proceed?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: What do you mean "data" -- do you mean the tags?

Comment: result of contents = some text1<br>more text<br>name<br?<li>list 1</li>Theend

Comment: Your post isn't tagged with "jQuery" -- but you could take a look at it its `text` method: http://api.jquery.com/text/ .

Comment: So you want get the `innerHTML` but without `style` attribute and its value?

Comment: @user3848973, edit your question instead of posting a comment.

Comment: Since your HTML is invalid, it's difficult to suggest a proper solution. If you don't want get HTML, then use `innerText` or `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`. Wait, in your comment you say you *do* want to get the HTML?? I'm confused now.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340449/is-there-a-way-to-get-innertext-of-only-the-top-element-and-ignore-the-child-el

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a *Really* primitive example:

```
var original_id1 = document.getElementById('id1'),
    cloned_id1 = original_id1.cloneNode(true); // deep clone

// find all ".class1" elements
var class1_elements = cloned_id1.getElementsByClassName('class1');
// remove .class1 elements from clone
for (var i = 0; i < class1_elements.length; i++){
  var c1 = class1_elements[i], p = c1.parentNode
  p.removeChild(c1);
}

// remaining HTML
alert(cloned_id1.innerHTML);

// remaining text content(s)
alert(cloned_id1.textContent);
```

[exmaple](http://jsfiddle.net/2rRPW/)