# How to get element value in Angular

Tags: angular

I have element as below:

```
<li class="someClass">value1<span>value2</span></li>
```

The above list element is generated through vanila js so the click event is bind to it as below:

```
const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll(".someClass"));
  list.forEach(ele => ele.addEventListener('click', this.getListValue.bind(this)));

getListValue(element)
{
 console.log('output', element.target.innerText)
}
```

In output I get on IE:

```
output value1 value2
```

chrome:

```
 output value1
```

I need only value1. Is there a way to get value of li tag for given scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Why do you even want to read elements from your templates?

Comment: @Amadán I need value of element to do some further action. In my case li element is a dropdown for search input and when user click on an li (i.e one of the item from dropdown) I want to grab that value and show some results on next page.

Comment: If you using Angular(-JS), then use ng-model and not read any content from HTML.

Comment: @Justinas I am using Angular (5.2). and I can't add [(ngModel)] as creating multiple li using vanila js code.

Comment: @Simer why are you doing that? create multiple <li> using *ngFor!

Comment: @Simer You might also want to have a look into [reactive forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms), using FormGroup, FormBuilder and FormArray.

Answer (score 1):

You're adding elements to the DOM that you then want to read again using vanilla JS? I'm having some trouble understanding what this has to do with using Angular or not, and why you'd want this...

Angular explicitly discourages messing with the native elements yourself. Also, you already had the value when generating the element, why bother reading it again? If you're going to insist on this approach anyways, you might as well add the on click when generating your html, where you should already have value1.

Anyhow, assuming you really have a valid use case for your approach and aren't just glueing copy pasted code together while completely ignoring the Angular concept (or any concept really), have a look at:
[Is there a way to get innerText of only the top element (and ignore the child element's innerText)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340449/is-there-a-way-to-get-innertext-of-only-the-top-element-and-ignore-the-child-el)