# JavaScript: Get textContent from element (with nested children) ignoring specific child

Tags: javascript

I'm hoping to get the `textContent` of an element (including text within nested children) but ignore a specific element which has text.

For example, such that

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="exclude-text">Exclude me</div>
  <div class="another-class">Add this text</div>
  And this text here
</div>
```

Performing `element.textContent` returns `Exclude me Add this text And this text here` whereas I'd just like `add this text And this text here`.

My possible solution would be to iterate through `childNodes` while checking if `classList.contains("exclude-text")` but how would I still get the `And this text here`?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9340449/is-there-a-way-to-get-innertext-of-only-the-top-element-and-ignore-the-child-el, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3442394/using-text-to-retrieve-only-text-not-nested-in-child-tags

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right track looping through nodes. Do it recursively, building up the text of the text nodes, and recursing into elements if they don't match an `exclude` selector (which could be a group [`".a, .b"`], if you want to exclude multiple classes or similar):

```js
function getTextExcept(element, exclude) {
    return worker(element);
    
    function worker(node, text = "") {
        if (node.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE) {
            text += node.nodeValue;
        } else if (node.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
            if (!node.matches(exclude)) {
                for (const child of node.childNodes) {
                    text = worker(child, text);
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
}
console.log(getTextExcept(
    document.querySelector(".container"),
    ".exclude-text"
));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="exclude-text">Exclude me</div>
  <div class="another-class">Add this text</div>
  And this text here
</div>
```

An alternative approach is to clone the entire structure, remove the elements you don't want the text of, and then use `.textContent` on the result. For a really large structure, that might be problematic in terms of memory (but it would have to be **really** large).

```js
function getTextExcept(element, exclude) {
    const clone = element.cloneNode(true);
    for (const child of clone.querySelectorAll(exclude)) {
        child.remove();
    }
    return clone.textContent;
}
console.log(getTextExcept(
    document.querySelector(".container"),
    ".exclude-text"
));
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="exclude-text">Exclude me</div>
  <div class="another-class">Add this text</div>
  And this text here
</div>
```